# import text file to mysql by python, data type automatically changed to varchar(63)

Tags: python, mysql

I have a text file looks like:

```
COLUMNNAME1    COLUMNNAME2    COLUMNNAME3 ...
user1          user1_data1    user1_data3
user2          user2_data1    user2_data3
...
```

Each column has different data type, I used

```
createQuery = "CREATE TABLE test(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, columnname1 datatype not null, ...., Primary key(id));"
cursor.execute(createQuery)
```

to create a table first.

Then I used

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datafile.txt', sep='\t', index_col = False, dtype = unicode)
df.to_sql(con=db, name='test', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

to import the data into the table. There's no error message. However when I checked the table, all the data types became to varchar(63) instead of the initial type I assigned in the create table command and one column contains long strings which is also truncated.

I want to use the INT, DATETIME types for some columns. I do not understand why all the data types are changed to varchar(63) automatically.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what `pd` is ???

Comment: Sorry, added now. pd is pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the `pandas` `to_sql` [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql):

```
if_exists : {‘fail’, ‘replace’, ‘append’}, default ‘fail’
  fail: If table exists, do nothing.
  replace: If table exists, drop it, recreate it, and insert data.
  append: If table exists, insert data. Create if does not exist.
```

You pass `if_exists='replace'` to the method `to_sql` so I guess this causes pandas to drop and recreate the table with some sort of default column types. Try passing `append` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you took time to read the FineManual for `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`, you would have found out by yourself:

> if_exists : {‘fail’, ‘replace’, ‘append’}, default ‘fail’
>
> ```
>     fail: If table exists, do nothing.
>     replace: If table exists, drop it, recreate it, and insert data.
>     append: If table exists, insert data. Create if does not exist.
> ```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

For the record, it took me exactly 23s to find this once I had confirmation you were talking about Pandas.